# Erro Xamarin - Curso MVA Iniciando com Xamarin.Forms - Video 3

Tags: xamarin

Ao compilar, me deparo com o seguinte erro:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 9:15. No Property of name ItemSource found
>
> "Unhandled Exception:
> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 9:15. No Property of name ItemSource found"

Dois botões: Break e Continue.
Caso clique em Break, é interrompido.
Caso clique em Continue, aparece o próximo erro:

> "An unhandled exception occured."

E o aplicação não roda.

Alguém já passou por esse problema?
O Código esta idêntico ao do Angelo Belchior no curso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, se eu não me engano, não é Item**s**Source?

Comment: Sim cara, é exatamente isto ¬¬'....

Muito obrigado pela força! =D